# .htaccess Negated Lookahead Regex malformed

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

The following is a segment from my .htaccess file. 
I want the following behaviour from Apache (currently the site is at localhost, but that shouldn't matter, right?):

If the requested resource is anything else other than

```
{site_url}/core
```

or

```
{site_url}/login
```

like

```
{site_url}/pseudo/path/name
```

the resource served must be

```
{site_url}/site/pseudo/path/name
```

Otherwise the URL served must be {site_url}/core or {site_url}/login, i.e. whatever was requested.

The .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>

    AliasMatch ^/(?!core|login)(/?.*)$ /site/$2
    Header add X-Enabled mod_alias

</IfModule>
```

But this doesn't seem to be working and returns an error. I am not very familiar with Regular Expressions and am trying to learn these. So what I have inferred from this expressions is:

If the expression after '/' , i.e. URI after site_url does not match core or login (?!core|login)) , and is followed by anything, inclusive of a sub-folder (/?.*)$ Optional slash, and anything following it, set the alias to /site/(anything that was matched in second parentheses).

The module is working, which I've checked using only the Header add part, the problem is the regex.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Leave off the **^** at the beginning. The regex you have would match `/pseudo/path/name` but not `{site_url}/pseudo/path/name`, because you're telling it that the text must begin with a **/**.

Also, be careful, because your regex is excluding things like `{site_url}/corel`. That's probably not going to be a problem unless you have other directories beginning with **core**, but if you really want to make it match anything other than `{site_url}/core` or `{site_url}/login`, use this regex:

```
/(?!core$|login$)(/?.*)$
```